# parsing DBF files and excluding lines that have a set date condition

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dbf

i have the following code:

```
parseAccountRecord = (dbfr) ->
  # We parse all records
  yesterday = moment().subtract(1,'days')
  createdAt = new moment(dbfr.SN_FCREATE, "YYYYMMDD")
  lastCreated = yesterday.diff(createdAt, 'days')
  updatedAt = new moment(dbfr.SN_LUPDATE, "YYYYMMDD")
  lastUpdated = yesterday.diff(updatedAt, 'days')
  if dbfr['@deleted'] or lastUpdated > 2 or lastCreated  > 2 then return null
```

basically i want to exclude all records with a lastUpdate date two days older or last created dates two days older from the set?

what am i missing?

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: This really seems like something that you'd do _in_ the database query, not after you get all the records back. Is that not possible?

Comment: i am running a parser that updates a REST application, so i need to only push records which have been updated or created in last day. so i was after on how to create that?